# JSONファイルのエラー箇所の特定

Tags: python, pandas, json

Python 3.9.10を使っています。
JSONファイルを読もうとしたときに、

```
import pandas as pd

json_file = open(ファイルパス, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
df = pd.read_json(json_file)
```

というようなことをやっていますが、エラーが出ることがあります。エラーの意味することが何なのかというかということは、この場では置いておいて、JSONデータのどこかに間違えがあるのだろうかと思います。
JSONファイルの中のどこに間違えがあるのか、行番号や文字位置などを特定する方法あありませんか？

今回の質問ではエラーの中身はとくに何でもよいのですが、一例です。

```
loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding object value
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あくまで Python で扱う場合にエラーをチェックしたいということでしょうか？それともツールを問わず JSON のチェックができれば良い？ (適切なタグを選ぶようにしてください)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Codeで JSONファイルを読み込むと, 問題のある箇所に赤の波線がでます。
(VS Codeに限らず多機能なエディターにはその手のツールが備わっている可能性も)

そのようなツール利用すると良いかもです。
参考: (code.visualstudio.com) [Editing JSON with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

使ってみました。デバッグ作業をするには便利そうですね。

Answer (score 1):

何時どんな風にチェック出来ればよいかが曖昧ですが、`json.tool`というモジュールが使えるのでは？
[コマンドラインインターフェイス- json --- JSON エンコーダおよびデコーダ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/json.html#module-json.tool)

> json.tool モジュールは JSON オブジェクトの検証と整形出力のための、単純なコマンドラインインターフェイスを提供します。

例えばこちらの記事で：
[Validate JSON data using Python](https://pynative.com/python-json-validation/)

こんな感じで報告されるとの記述が有ります。

```
error expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

---

[Validate JSON data using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54491156/9014308)
あるいはこちらの記事では必要なデータ構造の仕様も含めて厳密にチェックしたいという要望らしく、そこでは承認されていませんが、こんな回答があります。

こちらは承認された回答でJSON Schemaというものを使う。
[承認された回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54491882/9014308)
その[JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/)のドキュメントページ

上記JSON Schemaはオーバーキルなので標準のjsonモジュールのload/loadsを使って、exceptionが発生した場合にその内容を詳しく表示するというもの。
[基本的なエラーを見つけるだけの回答例](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467918/9014308)
内容的にはjson.toolで報告されるのと同等のものと思われます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

＞何時どんな風にチェック出来ればよいかが曖昧ですが、json.toolというモジュールが使えるのでは？

ソースコード実行中に位置情報（行番号）を取得して、コンソールなどに、エラー表示する、というようなことを想定していました。